# Dealing with Empty Values in a Running Total

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I was helped signifiacnlty a couple of time now and each time I run into a new problem. I believe this will be the last one for this particular project. The Query below is being used in a SSRS report I am creating, it is perfect excpet when there are ReportNo's that do not have any NonProductive time:
This is What I get when there is NonProductive Time on a particular date:

```
Reportno    RUNNINGTOTAL
 14              10.5
```

However, If I have a ReportNo that does not have any NonProductive I get this:

```
Reportno    RUNNINGTOTAL
```

Basically I just need it to find the last non empty value for this Sum.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT Reportno,
             SUM(SUM((ElapsedTime))) OVER (PARTITION BY NonProductive ORDER BY REPORTNO) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
      FROM dbo.DailyOperations o
      WHERE NonProductive IN (1) and WellID = 'ZCQ-5' AND JobID = 'Original'  
      GROUP BY ReportNo, NonProductive
     ) r
WHERE r.ReportNo = 14
ORDER BY ReportNo;
```

I tried changing Sum,Sum(MAX) I also tried SUM(CASE WHEN DailyOperations.Nonproductive = 1 THEN DailyOperations.ElapsedTime ELSE 0 END). I know that there is more than just Else 0, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a running total?

```
SELECT SUM(ElapsedTime) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
FROM dbo.DailyOperations o
WHERE NonProductive IN (1) AND
      WellID = 'ZCQ-5' AND
      JobID = 'Original' AND
      ReportNo <= 14
```

Comment: I was having issues with the parameters in the report. But after you posted this I realized that all I had to do was set up my ReportNo parameter like:   DailyOperations.ReportNo <=@ReportNo.  Thank you very much for this.